# How do I fade out a particular Rectangle object in XAML ? (Without knowing which one it will be)

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-7, storyboard

I loaded up blend and select rectangle #1 (there are 6) and created a simple fade out storyboard.

How can I easily apply that Storyboard to other rectangles programmatically ?

I was hoping I could simply say something like

`Storyboard.TargetNameProperty = this.rect2;`

and run the storyboard and that would fade out rectangle #2 but

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle' to
>   'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'   C:_Code\WP7_SL_WStest\wp7wstest\Views\GameTimer.xaml.cs    63  49  wp7wstest

My XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardFadeOut">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rect1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: thanks works great!! but what if I have TWO object I want to perform the storyboard animation on ? doing this wont work.. any simple way to have another instance act at the same time ?

Comment: Storyboard StoryboardFadeOut = this.FindName("StoryboardFadeOut") as Storyboard;
                    Storyboard.SetTarget(StoryboardFadeOut, rect2 as DependencyObject);
                    Storyboard.SetTarget(StoryboardFadeOut, rect4 as DependencyObject);
                    StoryboardFadeOut.Begin();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the Attached Property `Storyboard.SetTargetName`. Example

```
<Rectangle Name="rect1" IsHitTestVisible="True" Fill="Green"
           MouseEnter="rect_MouseEnter"
           MouseLeave="rect_MouseLeave"/>
<Rectangle Name="rect2" IsHitTestVisible="True" Fill="Red"
           MouseEnter="rect_MouseEnter"
           MouseLeave="rect_MouseLeave"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void rect_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle clickedRectangle = sender as Rectangle;
    Storyboard StoryboardFadeOut = this.FindName("StoryboardFadeOut") as Storyboard;
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(StoryboardFadeOut, clickedRectangle.Name);
    StoryboardFadeOut.Begin();
}
private void rect_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard StoryboardFadeOut = this.FindName("StoryboardFadeOut") as Storyboard;
    StoryboardFadeOut.Stop();
}
```

**Update**

As [decyclone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362218/decyclone) pointed out, it's better to use SetTarget instead when we have direct access to the Target. The updated MouseEnter method would look like this

```
private void rect_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard StoryboardFadeOut = this.FindName("StoryboardFadeOut") as Storyboard;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(StoryboardFadeOut, sender as DependencyObject);
    StoryboardFadeOut.Begin();
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `Storyboard.SetTarget()` instead when you have direct reference to target element.